# How would I correctly nest the if else statement? for the sum?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivisibleBy6or17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("How many Values To Read ? ");
        int amount = kbd.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[amount];
        int i = 0;
        double divisible = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (i < amount) {
            System.out.print("Enter Value : ");
            int nbr = kbd.nextInt();
            if (nbr %6 == 0 || nbr % 17 == 0) {
                divisible += nbr;
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (divisible == 0) {
            System.out.print("NONE DIVISIBLE");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Average: " + divisible/count);
        }
    }
}
```

so I want the sum of the numbers divisible by 16 or 17 so could I insert an if else for the sum then do the else for the average? I do not know where to insert the nested if statement for the sum

Comment: if (nbr %6 == 0 || nbr % 17 == 0){ your code divides by 6 not 16

Comment: correct indenting would help reading your code.

Comment: sorry i meant 6 but I got the average but im trying to get the output of the sum of numbers divisble by 6 or 17

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(divisible);` would print out the sum since you are just adding them all to that variable.

Please refer to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569527/how-would-i-manipulate-the-code-below-to-get-the-following-output/28570034#28570034

Comment: ok i understand that but how do i make sum an int i know i can cast it so (int) sum but when i do that if i read in 4 values the 110,888,34,16 the sum should be 35 and average should be 11.66666 however when i cast the sum to an int i get no outputs

Comment: sorry not cast sum but the divisible